# issue with bookmarks export batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file to backup the Firefox profile of the user.

```bash
set copycmd=/y
c:
if not exist "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming\Mozilla\firefox\profiles.ini" goto:EOF
cd "%userprofile%\appdata\roaming\Mozilla\firefox\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call set var1=%%j
cd profiles\%var1%
if not exist g:\backup (mkdir g:\backup)
copy places.sqlite g:\backup
```

It backed up not the profile of the user, but of the Administrator.

Any Idea why?

**output**

```
set copycmd=/y 
c:

C:\>if not exist "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\firefox\profiles.ini" goto:EOF
C:\>cd "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\firefox\" 
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox>for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call set var1=%j
```

It is going to the user Administrator, it should go to the domain\user